# Python for Android APK without dependencies

Tags: android, python, apk, sl4a

Is it possible to build an APK using Python for Android that doesn't need Python for Android to be there, i.e. it includes Python? If so, how?

Comment: do you want to export apk using python in your pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for: https://code.google.com/p/android-python27/

This will embed python into your apk. On first launch it will give you a dialog stating it is "installing". This part will install your script along with an integrated version of python. You are also able to embed different versions of python if you have a preference (2.6, 2.7, & 3.2).

- Tutorials to get started are found here: https://code.google.com/p/android-python27/w/list

Comment: You might also want to check the kivy version: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use py2exe to convert your programm to an .exe - File and then convert this .exe - File to an .apk - File.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to convert an exe file to apk.

Comment: This is COMPLETELY impossible. py2exe converts it to a Windows exe file; that has nothing to do with Android. -1.