# Python for Android

Tags: python

I had a look at Kivy,but the problem is it needs a virtual machine to run apps. Isn't there a way where python codes are directly converted to java bytecode which can be run by android without any virtual machine? What are the merits/demerits in terms of performance?

**May be something in jython which would help?**

Comment: This sounds like a question where if you did some actual research, you could ask a concrete question. Also, no-one knows what your problem with Kivy using a virtual machine is.

Comment: I need to develop an App which a user can directly install from the app store and use without worrying about an  headache like installing kivy enviroment.

Comment: How do you know you can't do that with Kivy?

Answer (score 2):

Try `SL4A` for running Python code directly on your device. It requires no compiling, conversion to bytecode or virtual machines.

More information [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

Also, you can download an IDE (I've used Eclipse, like in the tutorial you will find on the site), installed a plug-in, created my source files there and then uploaded them to my phone, if you're uncomfortable with writing code on your device.

Comment: SL4A does require to install SL4A scripting launcher right?

Comment: I think you're reffering to the .apk you have to install, right?

Comment: @AnmolNanda: You can distribute your applications in APKs that would require Python for Android. If you want it dependency-free, see this question I posted a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994251/python-for-android-apk-without-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This page has full instructions on how to package a Kivy app into an APK: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html

Answer (score 1):

I think some one mislead you a lot or you are confused about how things work with kivy.
I'll take this opportunity to try and make things a bit more clear.

Kivy can be used to build stand alone apk, only if you had searched kivy in [google play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kivy&c=apps&hl=en). This link shows a list of apps that mention kivy, there are a lot more apps there that use kivy and just don't mention that. There is also a partial user maintained [list](http://wiki.kivy.org/list_of_kivy_apps) you can look at. You can install the apps from google play and you'd see that they are self contained and don't require you to download anything extra.

There are very easy instructions available on how to build a apk in the link mentioned by @Marcins.

**Every** python code passes through the python interpreter usually pre-compiled to pyc, that's how python works even Java uses a virtual machine JVM, Android's implementation uses Dalvik VM. You can learn more about the VirtualMachines used in the languages like java/python [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_virtual_machines). The python interpreter/vm consumes the code and executes it natively, it doesn't convert it to java byte code.

if you need to make something that needs more performance then you can even use [cython](http://cython.org/) with kivy to get more speed.

Comment: this is correct, kivy runs python code, the python interpreter is sometime called a virtual machine (because, much like java VM, it's some kind of VM), but everything (including the python interpreter) is bundled into the apk, you don't need to install anything else, kivy apps are self contained.